# What is the meaning of the coordinate structure in the double tangent space of a manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, classical-mechanics, tangent-bundle

Let $Q$ be an n-dimensional Riemanian manifold and $TQ$ its tangent boundle. In coordinates, the elements of $TQ$ can be written as $(x^i,v^i)$, where $x^i$ are the coordinates on $Q$ and $v^i=\dot x^i$. Now in this case it is easy to see that these coordinates have an intuitive meaning because if we think of a 2d manifold then $TQ$ is a plane and $x^i$ tells you the point, $v^i$ the direction so that a vector in $TQ$ can be identified.

I´m struggling to do the same, even for a 2d manifold, for the double tangent boundle. More specifically, a vector $z$ in $T_vTQ$ can be written as, if $v=(x^i,v^i)$, $z=(x^i,v^i,w^i,r^i)$, but I don´t understand what $w^i,r^i$ are.

Why is the horizontal part of $z$ then $z_{hor}=(x^i,w^i)$? I also don´t see what $\text{shape}$ $T_vTQ$ has, and therefore what $\text{shape}$ $TTQ$ has. is there a way to see it, even just for 2d manifolds, that continues the intuition for $TQ$?

Comment: Note that $TQ$ is not a plane in general.

Comment: Yes, that is why I was wondering if it is possible to first see what TTQ is in the case when TQ is a plane, to then understand the more general case

Comment: If $Q$ is a plane, it is in particular a vector space, so that $TQ \simeq Q \times Q$ and $T(TQ) \simeq Q\times Q \times Q \times Q$

Comment: Horizontal and vertical parts of $v \in TTM$ have definitions using the metric tensor and the Levi Civita connection. These concepts arise naturally in the coordinate free description of the geodesic equation and more generally Lagrange's equations.